# How to select images with numbered filenames and append all images together horizontally

Tags: python

I have several image files whose names are numbered 1-300. (frame1jpg, .. ,frame300.jpg)

I would like to append all images together horizontally by select (n) and Start/End file.

And I can change (n) and start/end files.

> Example1: (n) = 5, start frame5.jpg end frame30.jpg. After that append from frame5.jpg, frame10.jpg,..,frame25.jpg

> Example2: (n) = 7, start frame0.jpg end frame25.jpg. After that append from frame0.jpg, frame7.jpg,..,frame21.jpg

Now I have code to append image as below.

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

images = [Image.open(x) for x in ['frame45.jpg','frame55.jpg','frame65.jpg','frame75.jpg','frame85.jpg']]
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

x_offset = 0
for im in images:
  new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
  x_offset += im.size[0]

new_im.save('00final.png')
```

I'd like to change from.

```
images = [Image.open(x) for x in ['frame45.jpg','frame55.jpg','frame65.jpg','frame75.jpg','frame85.jpg']]
```

To easy define (n) and Start/End file.

Comment: What is your question / problem here?

Comment: @the_strange I'd like to append images by choose file number name to append it. I already revised my question.

Comment: At a quick glance, your code seems to be ok (without me knowing any PIL details). What is the precise problem you're having? Is the output image simply incorrect, or something else?

Comment: @9769953 I'd like to change from.
    '''images = [Image.open(x) for x in ['frame45.jpg','frame55.jpg','frame65.jpg','frame75.jpg','frame85.jpg']]'''
To easy define (n) and Start/End file.

Comment: Ah, right. So the rest of the code is actually irrelevant for the problem/question at hand. But it looks like your question has already been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the list of filenames given your `start`, `end` and `step`:

```
def get_images(start, end, step):
    file_list = [f"frame{i}.jpg" for i in range(start, end, step)]   
    return [Image.open(x) for x in file_list]

images = get_images(start, end, step)
```